# How to run powershell script on target computing due double hopping issues?

Tags: powershell, kerberos, credssp

I'm using powershell `PS-Session` to connect from `kali` to target system which is `server A`, on the server A, there is module called `PowerSploit` installed, and I want to run `Get-DomainSID`, I'm able to get the SID when I run the command locally, the scripts talks to DC which is `server B` using ldap filter.

To overcome double-hoping issues I have tested following setups, but fails to provide me desired results.

`Case#1`

```
$cred = Get-Credential hacklab.local\administrator
[192.168.0.102]: PS C:\Users\administrator\Documents> Invoke-Command -ComputerName attacker-win10 -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Command -ComputerName hacklab-dc -Credential $Using:cred -ScriptBlock {hostname}}               HACKLAB-DC                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[192.168.0.102]: PS C:\Users\administrator\Documents> Invoke-Command -ComputerName attacker-win10 -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Command -ComputerName hacklab-dc -Credential $Using:cred -ScriptBlock {Get-DomainSID}}
The term 'Get-DomainSID' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-DomainSID:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : attacker-win10
```

`Case#2`

```
[192.168.0.102]: PS C:\Users\administrator\Documents> Invoke-Command -ComputerName hacklab-dc -ScriptBlock { Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Demo -RunAsCredential 'hacklab.local\administrator' -Force }
[hacklab-dc] Connecting to remote server hacklab-dc failed with the following error message : A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting 
Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (hacklab-dc:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 1312,PSSessionStateBroken
```

on `case#2` I get the credentials prompt where I enter the password and it works as expected in both the above cases the commands are failing over PS-SESSION.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2nxx.png)

**UPDATE**
@Jdweng, thanks

```
┌──(asad㉿Yah-Aleemo)-[/home/asad]
└─PS> Invoke-Command -Session $offsecsession -ScriptBlock &{Invoke-Command -ComputerName hacklab-dc -Credential hacklab.local\administrator -ScriptBlock &{Get-DomainSID} }                                                                   

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
14     Job14           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            Microsoft.PowerShell.Man…
Invoke-Command -ComputerName hacklab-dc -Credential hacklab.local\administrator -ScriptBlock &{Get-DomainSID}
```

I guess instead of `@` you want to use `&` also, the command works but it has opened

```
└─PS> Invoke-Command -Session $offsecsession -ScriptBlock {Receive-job 14}                                             
Receive-Job: The command cannot find a job with the job ID 14. Verify the value of the Id parameter and then try the command again.
```

I'm unable to retrieve the output of the job

Comment: Same error as another posting earlier today.  You needs to add a ampersand (2X) to get rid of error : -ScriptBlock @{ Invoke-Command -ComputerName hacklab-dc -Credential $Using:cred -ScriptBlock @{hostname}}  A cmdlet has to be the first item in a command.  Putting the ampersand in the script makes the block a child process.  Also hostname is not a cmdlet : -ScriptBlock {hostname}

Comment: Thank you, please see my update on the question above.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: Error indicates cannot find cmdlit Get-DomainSid.

Comment: Yes, how can i make it find the Get-DomainSID?